# Boostrap not overriding my own css

Tags: css, overriding

Im getting started with bootstrap and I wanted to make simple select using boostrap but somehow it ruins my page. I thought boostrap will override my own css but its not happening, why?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-select.min.css"/>
<script href="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script href="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script href="bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"  />
```

After swaping places(used links to make sure they are correct):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"  />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Select looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nUr3.png

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the order you have your imports set. Imports further down get priority (overwrite) over imports prior to them.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"  />
```

Should be changed to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

(put the file you want to have less priority first)

Comment: Doesn't work actually, I've changed and now my select looks pretty bad (link in 1st post)

Comment: Could you add your html and your styles.css into the description?

Answer (score 1):

you can override with `!important` eg: `color: red!`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Move all your JS at the bottom css on the top and try to remove the "screen" in the css part

< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" **media="screen"**  />

**to**

< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-select.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<body>
.....
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script href="bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, welcome on StackOverflow, although your post looks good (I may mention I didn't test it), you should explain in which ways this is a solution (in other words, what did the OP did wrong).

Answer (score 0):

The order of external style sheets only matters if all the sheets have styles with same selectors, properties, weights, and specificity. That's unlikely to be true.

So what I would do is first disable your sheet and view your web page with just Bootstrap. Press F12 in the browser and pull up the actual style cascade window and see which rules are being applied. I can tell you that you likely have a mush of styles in Bootstrap being inherited by the select element. Bootstrap starts by trying to change the core "select" element's margins, fonts, and line-heights. It then layers over custom styles via classes it applies over those. Then look at the wrapper div or block element holding it. Bootstrap loves floats which break elements out of the page and blocks holding them.

Now add your sheet back in and look at what was cascaded down that added to Bootstrap's styles.

Even if their classes cascaded over your styles, your styles might be changing properties Bootstrap does not affect. So I would turn off all styles in your sheet that affect "select" elements, then carefully bolt in your own select styles to ADD not change Bootstrap's styles. I would only change simple effects like colors or the outer block level elements the "select" sits in.